# WTSEnumerateSessions не возвращает сессии

Tags: c#, winapi

**Изначальная задача:**
Запустить на удаленном ПК блокнот (т.е. отловить интерактивную сессию и в ней запустить)
**Как это работает:**
Есть 2 приложения. 1 - сервис, 2 - приложение, которое регистрирует и стартует сервис.
Оба приложения копируются на конечный пк и через WMI вызывается "запускатор сервиса". (т.е. сервис создается локально, на конечном ПК)
Внутри сервис вызывает WTSEnumerateSessions и дергает с нее активную сессию. Тут все ок
**Как это не работает:**
Есть 1 приложение - сервис. Приложение копируется на конечный ПК, но
регистрация и запуск сервиса происходит на клиентском приложении. (т.е. сервис создается удаленно) Далее сервис работает с совершенно тем же кодом как и в первом случае, только WTSEnumerateSessions не возвращает списка сессий (GetLastWinError = 0, т.е. дело не в правах. Он их просто не видит), соответственно запуска блокнота не происходит.

```
IntPtr server = IntPtr.Zero;
server = WTSOpenServer(ServerName); --изначально этой строки не было. И все работает в первом варианте. Но добавление не решило для второго
IntPtr ppSessionInfo = IntPtr.Zero;
Int32 count = 0;
Int32 retval = WTSEnumerateSessions(server, 0, 1, ref ppSessionInfo, ref count);
```

В обоих случаях сервисы на удаленном ПК работают от имени СИСТЕМА
**Вопрос собственно:**
список сессий не возвращается потому, что сервис в этом случае создается удаленно?
Как то можно обойти?
**Решено:** не там проверял результат WTSEnumerateSessions. ppSessionInfo кастился в int, и работало норм на первом сервисе. А на втором почему то не влазило в инт, и падало в оверфлоу

Comment: Прикольно это всё, а зачем? Чтобы блокнот от имени СИСТЕМА запустить? Насколько мне известно, винда нативно позволяет запускать софт на удаленной машине, вообще без участия какого-либо софта на удаленной машине.

Comment: Про то что сервисы запускаются от имени СИСТЕМА, я уточнил на всякий случай. А что бы блокнот (любое приложение с ГУИ) открылся и пользователь его видел - нужно получить токен активного пользователя. Без участия - будет запускаться от имени клиента-админа и пользователь ГУИ не увидит.

Comment: Блокнот - это утрирование. Чтобы подключить сетевой диск, кинув команду на удаленку - нужно чтобы команда выполнилась от активного пользователя. иначе диски подключаться к административной учетке. Пример для чего нужно вытащть активный токен

Comment: [Это](https://superuser.com/a/42540) не в тему? Кстати, по поводу подключения сетевых дисков и т.д. Такие штуки обычно настраиваются с помощью политик контроллера домена.

Comment: [Про обработку ошибок](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53740899/12888024) - читать комменты под постом.

Comment: вам не проще написать приложение, которое запускать у каждого пользователя в автозагрузке? которое в свою очередь будет к примеру периодически обращаться к веб-серверу или базе данных и проверять, а нет-ли для моего пользователя команд, и выполнять их если есть. по-моему надежнее и проще чем запускать службу и пытаться получить токен пользователя, который к примеру может зарубить антивирусное ПО или не дать прав службе групповые политики для конкретного терминала. И если вам нужно просто подключить диск то это проще, конечно, сделать через ГПО с выполнением в контексте пользователя.

Comment: попробуйте сделать простейшее консольное приложение с вашим кодом, и запустите его от админа на сервере где перечисление не срабатывало, дабы быть уверенными на 100%, что дело не в правах/GPO.

Comment: Кроч, моя вина. В базовом коде была строка long current = (int)ppSessionInfo; и на первом сервисе все норм было. а на втором, почему то в int не влазило и вываливаось в оверфлоу. Что странно, т.к. набор данных возвращался одинаковый. long current = (long)ppSessionInfo решило проблему. А количество сессий не в том месте проверял. поэтому 0 было.

Comment: написать приложение не прощу) идея была в написании админской утилиты которая может рассылать произвольные команды. Реализовано через сервис т.к. своеобразная надстройка над логикой PsExec, только по реализации CsExec